# Comparing Rust and Solidity hash of big number or hex

Tags: solidity, web3js, rust

I noticed that if I hash ordinary string using Rust and web3.sha3 I would get the same result. But if the number is big number or hex which would necessitate the inclusion of {encoding: 'hex'} as optional arg to web3.sha3 my result from Rust and web3.sha3 would not be same . So, my question is what should I do to my Rust input before hashing it? 
For Rust I am using multihash which is a thin wrapper.

```
let nm_str1 = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ea";
/let output = encode(Hash::Keccak256, &nm_str1.as_bytes()).unwrap();
//JavaScript
const nmStr1 = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ea";//
let output web3.sha3(nmStr1, {encoding: 'hex'}
```

Comment: The string is hexadecimal, not base64.

Comment: @smarx .... I mentioned hex in my sketch but I have to show what I have done. BTW, thanks.

Comment: Why did you try base64 decoding something that wasn't base64 encoded?

Comment: I checked what {encoding: 'hex'} does? I found that it prompts a function call before processing, hex.parse .. And I later checked what this function does? I noticed that sort of decodes the hex.

Comment: Yes, it does. I was just confused as to why you used `base64::decode` when you seemed to already know that the encoding was hex, not base64.

Comment: I have removed it

Comment: So, what are you suggesting for me to do?

Comment: Did my answer not work for you?

Comment: Awesome!! I have searched everywhere for something list rustc_hex and I didn't find. Looks like it is not commonly used. However, thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is a hexadecimal string, so you have to first convert from hex to bytes.

The code below produces the right output for me (same as `web3.sha3` except for a prefix which I assume comes from the multihash encoding):

```
extern crate multihash;
extern crate rustc_hex;

use multihash::{encode, Hash};
use rustc_hex::{FromHex, ToHex};

fn main() {
    let hex = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ea";
    let bytes = hex.from_hex().unwrap();


    println!("{}", encode(Hash::Keccak256, &bytes).unwrap().to_hex());
}
```

For those who want the non-multihash version:

```
extern crate rustc_hex;
extern crate tiny_keccak;

use rustc_hex::{FromHex, ToHex};
use tiny_keccak::Keccak;

fn main() {
    let hex = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ea";
    let bytes = hex.from_hex().unwrap();

    let mut h = Keccak::new_keccak256();
    h.update(&bytes);
    let mut res: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
    h.finalize(&mut res);

    println!("{}", res.to_hex());
}
```